# Youtube Iframe API Svelte document.create error

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am trying to use Youtube videos using Youtube Iframe API in my Svelte application. I get a variable is. not defined error. Here is my code

```js
<script context="module">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.

    onMount(() => {
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    });

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

     
    // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
    //    after the API code downloads.

    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
        console.log('hello')
      }

</script>


<script>
    export let videoId
</script>
<div>
    YT-Component VID: {videoId}
</div>
```

My error is: `tag is not defined ReferenceError: tag is not defined at Youtube.svelte:10:4 at async instantiateModule (/Users/emrahgunel/Desktop/NAZ-BRAND-MichelobUltra/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-80fe9c6b.js:50286:9)`

How can I fix this error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`tag` is scoped to `onMount`, you should move your other code that interacts with it there as well.

Also, you usually should not use functions like `document.getElementsByTagName` because they create unnecessary dependencies on structure. Generally, `bind:this` is used to get access to specific elements within a component.

In the case of adding scripts, you can just append them to `document.body`.

Assigning `window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` will cause issues when you have more instances of the component as this overwrites any existing event handler.